# how to stop visual studio 2013 automatically changing form size

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am developing project for a winform c# application in my desktop with 1080p resolution. The size of the form is 1216*939. However, I change another computer with 2560*1800 resolution to continue developing this application. The size of the form and layout will be automatically changed when i open this project. The following link are the pictures for the case I describe

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zbl8zwcpjnr7kti/aIBuvAWrUs

Comment: Perhaps also try setting the `Maximum Size` property to your desired size?

Comment: The image link is broken. Can you please provide it again? If you use the [edit] form functionality to upload the image, it will never vanish again.

Comment: Also, if the answer helped you, please accept it. Both you and the answerer will gain reputation points by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, solved by changing the percentage of presentation of the resolution of my monitor from 125 to 100.

[image]